# Windows Update showed "Downloading updates 95%" for hours

Tags: windows, performance, windows-update, download, troubleshooting

I was using Windows 10 Home, version 1607 (OS build 14393.693).

The computer was a bit slow earlier today. Task Manager indicated that "Service Host: Local System" was making very heavy use of the hard drive bandwidth; it looked like the machine was probably disk-bound, not CPU-bound. Sysinternals Process Monitor indicated that this was probably because of some Windows Update activity.

I opened the Settings app and realized that this was correct. Windows Update was downloading: Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB4013429).

It said "Downloading updates 95%".

And it continued to say "Downloading updates 95%", for hours.

Was it stuck?

Comment: Process Monitor is good for troubleshooting errors from various API calls (did it look in the wrong directory and get file not found?  access denied?  sharing violation because another process had the file open?  searched another directory first and found a file there, so it didn't even open the customized one?).   But for statistics (similar to popular Linux tools `iostat` or `vmstat`), the "Resource and Performance Monitor" tool (`perfmon.exe`), which can be reached from a button in Task Manager "Performance" tab, is a lot more useful.  sysInternals' Process Explorer also has helpful stats.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I wasn't using Process Monitor to collect statistics. I used Task Manager to collect statistics. I discovered that the machine was probably disk-bound, and that "Service Host: Local System" was the culprit. Then I used Process Monitor to look at the service host and see which of the many services was accessing the disk. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, it's just more useful to look at Resource Monitor.  In Process Monitor if you have more than one process making a lot of file accesses, it's really hard to tell which one has more or by how much.  With Resource Monitor it's easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The three types of Windows Update logs

Windows Update has the capability to be exceedingly windy and verbose. Even if it only downloads one small update, it can still generate three types of logs telling you what happened.

These three types of logs are:

- The text file which the PowerShell `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` cmdlet saves to your desktop.

  - This is a static file; to update it, you must run the cmdlet again.
- Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > WindowsUpdateClient > Analytic.

  - This is an analytic log, so you must [unhide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766275(v=ws.11).aspx) and [enable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749492(v=ws.11).aspx) it, then must wait quite a while for it to start filling up with the first few items.
- Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > WindowsUpdateClient > Operational.

  - This log is visible by default.

## What I found

I looked at the first of these three logs, then in a recently-created subfolder of `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download`. I soon realized that Windows Update was indeed still downloading updates, even though the progress indicator appeared stuck at 95%.

## The end of the story

Eventually (maybe after several hours), Windows Update finished its downloading. It announced that the updates were ready to install.

Comment: if it hangs, search the update on update catalog http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KBNUMBER

Comment: @magicandre1981: Why would doing such a search help me?

Comment: it helps to download and install the MSU. I also have this from time to time that Wu is slow to download updates

Answer (score -1):

Tried all the possible suggestions DISM, cleanups, etc, but someone (unfortunately, lost source solution link) found the only working for me solution - applying **Servicing Stack Update** from [this page](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=servicing%20stack%20update) before cumulative updates finally unblocked chain of updates.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: This is an extremely common situation when the same answer solves multiple questions, which nobody will close as duplicate if you mark them because they are not similar enough. High chance that both my answers were only working solutions for some cases, and very hard to find.